# Agent disappears when reaching an attractor

Tags: anylogic

I have a set of agents who should be parking at 4 attractors. I use the moveTo block.

I followed the method suggested in this thread [AnyLogic how to set attractor choice to both free and random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267539/anylogic-how-to-set-attractor-choice-to-both-free-and-random). The snapshot is below.

My agents disappeared on reaching the attractors. But when I chose "is placed (jumps) to" the agents stayed put but I couldn't proceed to the next state (I'm using statechart to control the movement of the agent).

Is there additional step that I should do to either keep the agent in place or get it to move out of the flowchart?

[moveTo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2MCq.png)

Comment: Do they disappear or actually appear on top of each other? Do they disappear on arrival or not even visible during movement? Note that you can have 1000s of agents on top of each other at 1 attractor, so maybe this confuses you?

Comment: No they are not on top of each other. I found the issue why the agents disappeared. It was caused by the service block that receives the agent in the next flowchart. But now I have a new problem. When I free the attractor from the agent, it doesn't return to the collection. Instead I got null. How do I put back the attractors to the collection?

Comment: Please ask new questions in a new issue always. SOF doesn't work like a forum

Comment: Some tips on using SOF to your advantage as an AnyLogic dev: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author found the answer herself:

> I found the issue why the agents disappeared. It was caused by the service block that receives the agent in the next flowchart.