# Two agents standing on same attractor while other attractor is free in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have two delays with a single resource pool(capacity 6) and same single rectangular node. Let's say 2 agents enter in the rectangular node and both are coming for different delays then why they are standing on the same attractor when there is free attractors available.

I am making sure in rectangular node the number of agents always equal or less the the number of attractors so space is not the issue.
How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

I am making sure in rectangular node the number of agents always equal or less the the number of attractors so not having enough space is not an issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AnyLogic Attractor weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972040/anylogic-attractor-weird-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Attractors have no concept of being "full". You can have a million agents at 1 attractor.

Also, there is no build-in way to manage this.

You need to do it yourself, for example via a conceptual agent that has a `p_MyAttractor` parameter and an internal `boolean v_IsFull` variable.

Or you split your nodes to have 1 attractor only, and manage moving your agents to the node that has no other agent (but the same core problem remains: nodes also have no concept of "full" except if you use transporters or pedestrians).

You can bypass all these issues by going full-blown agent-based networks but this is highly advanced stuff, see https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGJP0k1miFbQ0XfchiMK9nxj-qr42dyw